# Chrome APP/Extension download file from URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I've been researching and i did not found anything about that.

I need a chrome application that will run on Chrome OS be able to download a file (image, mp3, video, etc) and then display the content as HTML.

I mean if the app download a video, then play it on a video tag. The same for a image...download it and display on img tag.

Thanks!!

Comment: So what is the problem? You can use [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and [Filesystem](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) if you dont know.

Comment: You have a very confusing title that doesn't match the question. Could you fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Chrome App documentation on [Handling external content](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external). It provides a good overview.

A short version:

1. Declare the origins you're going to access in the manifest.
2. Fetch the resource via XHR (or, indeed, [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)).
3. Use the response as a `blob:` (you can plug it into a `<video src="...">`, for instance).
4. Optionally, [save the resource](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_apps#saving-locally) locally.

Comment: Thank you! I was doing like that but not using blob on Src!! I used base64 and some other things.

Answer (score 1):

I also worked with this issue, here a working example of saving to filesystem + showing on screen:

```
var video = document.getElementById("video");

fetch('http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.blob();
  })
  .then(function(myBlob) {
    var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
    video.src = objectURL;

    var config = {type: 'saveFile', suggestedName: chosenEntry.name};
    chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry(config, function(writableEntry) {
      writeFileEntry(writableEntry, myBlob, function(e) {
        output.textContent = 'Write complete :)';
      });
    });
  })
```